# Materialize, efecto hover, active & visited en etiqueta button html5

Tags: css3, materialize, botón, gulp-sass

Estoy haciendo estilos de botones dentro de **gulp-sass** aplicando efectos como `hover`, `active` y `visited` con *Materialize*, pero al momento de dar clic al botón y soltarlo me pone un color predeterminado del framework antes mencionado (**waves-light**).
Cuando estoy definiendo los colores, activo los parámetros `background-color` de inicio con `hover, active y visited`, pero no lo toma en cuenta, ya intente hacerlo directamente en el *CSS*, pero no funciona. les dejo un fragmento del código en CSS:

```css
.bton-fb {
width: 200px;
height: 50px;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: #3b5998;
}

button.bton-fb:hover {
background-color: #5772ac; 
}

button.bton-fb:active {
background-color: #14306b; 
}

button.bton-fb:visited {
background-color: #14306b; 
}
```

```html
<div>
<h1 class="">Ejemplo de Botónes</h1>
<button class="waves-effect bton-fb">Hover me! ;)</button>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿has intentado background en lugar de background-color?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con `!important` en el valor que quieras que prevalezca:

```
button.bton-fb:hover {
    background-color: #5772ac !important;
}
```

Comment: ya lo intente, pero no funciona y no entiendo porque

Answer (score 0):

pega tu css al final del archivo materialize y saca ese class="" del h1, me funciono sin problemas, no te puedo enviar un print de la imagen ya que tengo accesos bloqueados aqui en mi trabajo

y como te decia agregue el css en el archivo materialize.css ( no usando el cdn)

avisame como te va

Comment: gracias por el apoyo, pero ya resolví el problema en cuestión.

Comment: el problema se soluciono quitando **active** y **visited**, así como declarando la pseudo clase _focus_ @Francisco Muñoz